# explicitly setting "pretty print" formatting for Graph API request

Tags: json, facebook, facebook-graph-api

When querying the Graph API with a 'known' browser the JSON output is formatted in a way to make it easy for humans to read.  If the query is done with any other browser then it outputs everything on one line.

How do you explicitly make the request so that the formatting is not done?  I'm sure I've seen it somewhere, but I can't seem to find it now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `pretty` parameter controls it. So `https://graph.facebook.com/foo?pretty=0` always prints without extra whitespace, while `https://graph.facebook.com/foo?pretty=1` always prints with extra whitespace, and omitting it causes the default behavior of switching based on user-agent.